# Python - Print updating counter not working

Tags: python

This is my code. The goal is to print a counter that updates the number of the page that's being checked within the same lane, replacing the old one:

```
import time

start_page = 500
stop_page = 400

print 'Checking page ',

for n in range(start_page,stop_page,-1):
    print str(n),
    time.sleep(5) # This to simulate the execution of my code
    print '\r',
```

This doesn't print anything:

```
$ python test.py
$
```

I'm using Python 2.7.10, the line that causes problems is probably this `print '\r',` because if I run this:

```
import time

start_page = 500
stop_page = 400

print 'Checking page ',

for n in range(start_page,stop_page,-1):
    print str(n),
    time.sleep(5) # This to simulate the execution of my code
    #print '\r',
```

I have this output:

```
  $ python test.py 
    Checking page  500 499 498 497 496 495 494 493 492 491 490 489 488 487 486 485 484 483 482 481 480 479 478 477 476 475 474 473 472 471 470 469 468 467 466 465 464 463 462 461 460 459 458 457 456 455 454 453 452 451 450 449 448 447 446 445 444 443 442 441 440 439 438 437 436 435 434 433 432 431 430 429 428 427 426 425 424 423 422 421 420 419 418 417 416 415 414 413 412 411 410 409 408 407 406 405 404 403 402 401
  $
```

Comment: I just entered this into my interpreter and it works fine.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: Me too. How are you trying to run the above code ? Despite the fact that you have some extra commas in there... it should work fine

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: @leaf I suppose is 2.x since the OP is not using `()` around the `print ` statement

Comment: @Dex'ter Well he may be trying to run his program with a 3.x interpreter. He never said _why_ his code didn't print. He could be getting a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Dex'ter - The extra commas indicate specific behavior for the `print` statements.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.10, and really the script doesn't print anything, but the code in the for statement is being executed

Comment: Well, the code you posted does print something, so it doesn't represent whatever issue you're actually having. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Is like the \r deletes the whole line instead the last number printed, because I don't have any errors when running, just no output. Without the '\r' I have the output as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the comas after the print expressions:

```
print 'Checking page ',
print str(n),
print '\r',
```

PS: Since I got asked, the first thing to notice is that print is not a function it is a statement, hence it is not interpreted in the same way.
In the print case in particular, adding a ',' after the print will make it print the content without a newline.

In the case of your program, in particular, what it was doing is:

```
printing 'Checking page' -> NO \n here
printing n -> no \n here
printing '\r' -> again no '\n' here
```

Since you were not sending any new lines to the output, your OS didn't flush the data. You can add a sys.stdout.flush() after the print('\r') and see it changing if you want.

More on the print statement here.
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt

Why the hell I got downvoted? o.O

Comment: Why would commas be wrong in the OPs situation ? Even if they shouldn't be there, can they affect the code ?